# How to fix this issue Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot

I've installed openvpn and a tool to run as an admin then I restated my pc and it's stuck on a black screen with a lot of commands as I think all of the commands have an ok next to them except openvpn is Faield and it's keep blinking! Any help or I should install a fresh one again? Your help please guys.

Comment: Referring to this `and a tool to run as an admin`, what's the tool exactly ?  Also, If the tool is expected to modify system permissions, It could create a problem.

Comment: Also, In Linux, we don't have concept of `admin` rather `Root` or `Superuser`. To run any command or program with root privileges, just use [sudo](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo) or [su](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html). You don't need any third party tool at all for this.

Comment: I've tried to do a recovery mode like fixing system files and nothing happened still stuck in the same black screen and still blinking.